# Sharing session between 2 wars(having JSF) in one ear

Tags: session, jsf-2, websphere, myfaces, faces-config

I have one ear that contains 2 wars on a Websphere Application server v(8.5.5) .

I used session sharing ability in WAS to share the session between the 2 WARs.

Both of the WARs are using JSF 2.0 MyFaces implementation bundled with WAS.

The problem is after I navigate from first WAR to the second WAR using a link in a page in the first WAR, in the landed page in second war when I make any navigation using navigation rules in the second war faces-config.xml I got this error:

> No navigation case match for viewId /dir1/dir2/war2page1.xhtml, action #{springManagedBean.beanAction(param)} and outcome navigationOutcomeName

I tried to copy the navigation rules in the faces-context.xml in the second WAR to the faces-context.xml of the first WAR then it worked fine.

I doubt that the problem is caused by session sharing between 2 WARs, as it seems that when I navigate from first WAR to the second WAR it still searching for a navigation case in the faces-conext.xml of the first WAR which doesn't exist so I got this error.

Comment: Are you indeed implying that when you disable session sharing, the navigation case will automatically successfully resolve files in a different WAR?

Comment: Yes if i removed session sharing every things works fine, also if i navigate in one WAR without switching to the other WAR with the session sharing enabled every things works fine. The problem only shows when i navigate between the 2 wars. Also need to mention that I'm working with single class loader for the 2 wars with PARENT_FIRST strategy.

Comment: I have tried something, I have merged the navigation rules of faces-config.xml of the 2 WARs in one file and i put the merged file in the faces-config.xml for each WAR, evey thing works perfectly.